# Python: How to convert all values in a list to their ascii values?

Tags: python, list, ord

```
def encrypt_message(text, x):
  text = list(text)
  for y in text:
    ord(text)
```

returns ord() expected a string of length 1, but list found

Comment: You probably wanted to write `ord(y)` instead of `ord(text)`?

Comment: I wonder what the function is trying to accomplish. x is not used, and whatever it does, does not look like encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you passed the `text` to `ord` function you need to pass the `y`.

But as strings are iterable objects you can just loop over your string :

```
def encrypt_message(text, x):
     return [ord(i) for i in text]
```